# Problem with solving a system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I´m trying to solve this system of two ordinary differential equations:

$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=y(t)$$

$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}=-0.05y(t)-\sin(\pi/4)+F*\cos(0.7t)$$

where the initial condition is $y(0)=0.1$ and unknown is $y(t)$, which I know that I have to get from the second equation and pass it to the first equation, in order to find $x(t)$.

But at this point I'm unsure about which step should I take to continue. Do you have some hint for me, maybe some operations that I should take a look at next?

Comment: Solve first $y(t)$ and then after a integration we have $x(t)$.

Comment: Is the sine term really constant? Your strategy should be feasible. How far did you get with solving the second equation?

Comment: @Cesareo so should I get y(t) from the second equation first?

Comment: @LutzLehmann the problem is that I'm unsure about how to continue in the second equation.

Comment: This is a first-order linear DE, you can apply the solution formula or just an integrating factor.

Comment: As @LutzLehmann noted, multiply both parts by $e^{0.05t}$ and you will have something like $(e^{0.05 t} \cdot y)'=f(t)$